# How can we enable debugging mode on google glass for testing an android app on google glass?

Tags: android, debugging, google-glass

I am develop an application for google glasses but I dont know How we enable debug mode in google glass and how we change setting on google glasses ?

Comment: I am develop an application for google glasses ---> Lucky you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To connect ADB to Google Glass, you have to turn on debug mode on the device. Turn the Glass on with a one second press of the power button if it is off. Tap the touchpad on the side to get to the time and voice prompt screen.
Now swipe your finger on the touchpad toward the back of your head until you see the settings card.
Tap the touchpad to enter the settings menu. Swipe toward the front of your head until you see the device info card.[image]
Tap again to enter this card’s menu - this is a little tough to find because the corner isn’t ear marked like most cards that offer menus. Next swipe forward until you see the “Turn on debug” option. Now tap again to enable it. The option changes into “Turn off debug” in case you need to turn it off again.[image]
Now you can run a screen mirroring utility like Droid@Screen or Android Screen Monitor (ASM). Connect your Google Glass to your desktop or laptop by the cable or through the internet.