# How to enable the debug mode on Google Glass Enterprise Edition 2?

Tags: google-glass

It has already been asked in [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542577/how-can-we-enable-debugging-mode-on-google-glass-for-testing-an-android-app-on-g), but this seems to be the *Glass Explorer Edition*.

When I am tapping the device info tab in the *Enterprise Edition 2*, the default Android settings open up. They are almost unusable using the touchpad, so I am using [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) to control it.

Clicking `System -> About phone -> Build number` multiple times in *scrcpy* does not work. Tapping it via the touchpad is impossible due to that it's the bottommost entry and the touchpad is not sensitive enough.

How can I enable the debugging mode?

---

Background: I am currently on the [firmware version](https://developers.google.com/glass-enterprise/downloads/release-notes) `OPM1.190831.003` and I am trying to update it to the latest via the [flashing tool](https://developers.google.com/glass-enterprise/downloads/system-images).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the problem is: update the firmware (kind of a chicken-and-egg problem).

I was able to flash the system image `OPM1.200625.001` using an USB-A cable instead of the USB-C cable included with the Glass.

The commands for `adb`/`fastboot` were:

```
cd OPM1.200625.001_user_signed
adb reboot-bootloader
fastboot oem xx-force-unlock-all 1
fastboot flash bootloader bootloader.img
fastboot flash bluetooth bluetooth.img
fastboot flash dsp dsp.img
fastboot flash dtbo dtbo.img
fastboot flash modem modem.img
fastboot flash system system.img
fastboot flash vbmeta vbmeta.img
fastboot flash vendor vendor.img
fastboot flash userdata userdata.img
fastboot boot boot.img
```

You may notice that this differs from the flashing instruction in the `README.txt`.
This is due to that this error occurred to me:

```
...\OPM1.200625.001_user_signed> fastboot flash boot boot.img
fastboot: error: cannot get boot partition size
```

After the Glass has booted from `boot.img` this is not saved to the boot partition!
So after the system is booted:

1. skip the provisioning
2. enable the developer mode from the settings (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542577/how-can-we-enable-debugging-mode-on-google-glass-for-testing-an-android-app-on-g))
3. flash the firmware using the [flash tool](https://developers.google.com/glass-enterprise/downloads/system-images)

When the new firmware is flashed you can enable the developer mode from the Glass settings.

Happy hacking!