# Error updating Google Glass firmware using Mac w/ M1 CPU: fastboot: cannot get boot partition size

Tags: adb, google-glass, firmware, fastboot, android-firmware

I am updating the Firmware for the Google Glasses Enterprise 2 as stated on [google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass-enterprise/downloads/system-images).

I am getting the error while I am running this command on terminal `fastboot flash boot boot.img` It returns with an error as stated above `fastboot: error: cannot get boot partition size` . Well i tried two different versions of the System images as mentioned on [Google's website](https://developers.google.com/glass-enterprise/downloads/system-images). I tried to change it to `fastboot flash boot_a boot.img` but the same error.

I saw someone was having the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64533981/9076566) as well there but no solution. Do someone have idea how can we install the system image on it. I have skipped it and run other commands all goes well but the boot is not working which is why the it only shows me now recovery mode/fastboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is problem with new Mac Mini. Because Apple is not using Intel CPU in new Mac mini M1. flash.android.com cannot update the firmware with browser on Apple M1.

I completed the task with windows pc and everything worked well. I believe this would help someone using M1 processors.

Answer (score 5):

1. run `fastboot --help` and read somehow carefully
2. flash boot.img with `fastboot flash:raw boot boot.img`